# Best practices for php arrays, foreach and if statements

Tags: php, coding-style

So I am just learning best practices now and everybody has an opinion and I just want to find a nice clean way of coding which is not .... bad?

I have written the below. It works, No error outputs however I have a feeling this is terrible practice. this is in a Wordpress template.

```
<?php
$config['social-links'] = [
  'facebook'   =>  'https://www.facebook.com/usernamehere',
  'instagram'  =>  'https://www.instagram.com/usernamehere/',
  'twitter'  =>  null,
  'youtube'  =>  null
];
```

and in the template

```
<ul class="social-nav inline-blocks">
<?php
    global $config;
    $dir = get_template_directory_uri();
    foreach($config['social-links'] as $key => $value) if($value)
        echo "
            <li class='$key inlineBlock'>
                <a class='animate' target='_blank' href='$value'>
                    <span class='inner'>
                        <img class='injectSvg' data-src='$dir/images/social-icons/icon-$key.svg' alt='$key'>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
        ";
    ?>
</ul><!--END Social-nav-->
```

I have a feeling because I have left them open this is terrible? I know the below works and is correct but I dislike brackets...

```
foreach($config['social-links'] as $key => $value) {
    if($value) {

    }
}
```

I just ended up going with the below...

```
<ul class="socialNav inlineBlocks">
<?php
    global $config;
    foreach($config['social-links'] as $key => $value) {
        if($value) {
            echo '
                <li class="'. $key .' inlineBlock">
                    <a class="animate" target="_blank" href="'. $value .'">
                        <span class="inner">
                            <img class="injectSvg" data-src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/social-icons/icon-'. $key .'.svg" alt="'. $key .'">
                        </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            ';
        }
    } ?>
</ul><!--END SocialNav-->
```

Comment: any thing in "wordpress" is bad practice.

Comment: this is true. i pref laravel but that was not the question >_<

Comment: laravel is a framework worpress is a cms

Comment: @nogad eh i never said it was a CMS, i said i prefer to use it. also you can build your own CMS on a framework :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is terrible practice. If you don't have access to a templating engine (i.e. *Twig*), then using shorthand/templating PHP like below is the path you should be looking at:

```
<?php foreach($config['social-links'] as $key => $value): ?>
    <?php if($value): ?>
        <li class="<?php echo $key; ?>" inlineBlock">
             <a class="animate" target="_blank" href="<?php echo $value; ?>">
                <span class="inner">
                    <img class="injectSvg" data-src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/social-icons/icon-'. $key; ?>.svg" alt="<?php echo $key; ?>">
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is commonly known as [Alternative Syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) and is the way to go.